# Can make an abstract final class in java ?

Tags: java

I tried making an abstract class and final but i cant make a abstract final class in JAVA

> Abstract final class A{
>    Constructor() 
>   Body 
>   }

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: and only chuck norris can create objects of that/....

Comment: @ΦXocę웃Пepeúpaツ Or [Jon Skeet](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9134/jon-skeet-facts).

Comment: @shmosel LOL, yes, some one with such a rep.....

Comment: An `abstract` class is meant to be extended. `final` means it can **not** be extended. So it's simply nonsensical if that combination would be possible.

Comment: Consider reading the documentation. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2

Answer (score 4):

A `final` class can't be extended. An `abstract` class must be extended. That's the reason you can't have both at the same time.